# how to proteus simulation inrush current

Tags: simulation, safety, proteus, reverse-polarity, inrush-current

i've a reverse polarity protection , i want to check inrush current simulation , but i don't know how .

[image]

i read this , but i tried but doesnt work

[How to plot voltage vs current graph on Proteus Software?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351439/how-to-plot-voltage-vs-current-graph-on-proteus-software/352771#352771)

---

update :

i have removed resistor caps , put resistor load ,   and that what i got for simulation  :

[image]

---

update 2 :

i have made sweep analysis : increase battery voltage from 0 to 48 , and monitor it with monitoring resistor voltage

[image]

**is that simulation right ?**

---

update 3 
 [image]

Comment: You need to get ride of C4 and C3 and make C1 and C2 the same value but, a 1 farad value is likely to be too high. If you can plot output voltage across the load resistor, that tells you what the inrush current profile is.

Comment: so  its wrong to model load circuit with current source ? or it should be  resistor across current source , or only resistor  ?

Comment: You should model your load to how it really is but, to measure inrush currents you can model as a resistor. Let’s keep comments away from the previous question for my sanity on my small tablet because it’s hard to track where I am on the small screen.

Comment: yes sure   for comments on this question  , i have updated my question,  can u please check it

Comment: Ok, here’s where I can’t help Much. I don’t use proteus but, if it’s anything like micro cap, when you do a time or transient analysis, it might default to showing you a graph of the output voltage after it has settled down. In micro cap this is disabled by a radio button such as “start analysis from true zero” or words to that effect.

Comment: ok,  i tried to make analysis starting from zero till 48 volt , please check my update 2 for question

Comment: Do it for a longer time base so we can see it settle at 48 volts and please distinguish the traces that are drawn. Your battery voltage should be applied instantly and your capacitor value is too small. Make it 1 uF just to test things out and vary that value so you get a better feel.

Comment: the color code is in bottom right , i have make it up to 48 , i dont know if that battery voltage is instantly . but i have changed cap value but nothing change

Comment: i will download and try it with micro cap , can u till me how to do it with micro cap  ?

Comment: I don’t know proteus to help you further.

Comment: I won’t be around for the rest of day due to commitments but, bear in mind this is a question and answer site and not a training college.

Comment: @Andy aka yea sure , it would be great if i can contact u if that won't disturb or annoy u sir

Comment: I will search too for it . Thanks alot for your helpful answers

Comment: Where / what do you expect for I=CdV/dt?

Comment: @Tony i want to size the capacitor and see the capacitance effect on rise time and in rush current

Comment: I see well the model must be accurate too. Try this instead http://tinyurl.com/tbee8p9  and http://tinyurl.com/v6se7g8